# If $\det[v_1 \mid v_2 \mid v_3] = 2$, what is the value of $\det[v_{1} + v_{2} + v_{3} \mid v_{1} + 2v_{2} + 3v_{3} \mid v_{1} + 4v_{2} + 9v_{3}]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, determinant

Let $A$ = $\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \hspace{2 mm} v_2 \hspace{2 mm} v_3 \end{bmatrix}$ be a 3 x 3 matrix with column vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$.

If $det(A) = 2$, then what is $det \begin{bmatrix} v_1+v_2+v_3 \hspace{7 mm} v_1+2v_2+3v_3 \hspace{7 mm} v_1+4v_2+9v_3\end{bmatrix}$?

I then set up the matrix for the question:
$$det \left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \hspace{5mm} 1\hspace{5mm} 1 \\ 1\hspace{5mm} 2\hspace{5mm} 4 \\ 1\hspace{5mm} 3\hspace{5mm} 9 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}v_1\hspace{5mm} v_2\hspace{5mm} v_3\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

Through my calculation, the determinant of the first matrix (the coefficient matrix) is 2, multiplied by the determinant of the given matrix, will give **4** as a result.

I just want to check if what I am doing is right for this question.

Comment: I think you might have the product of the matrices the opposite way

Comment: But yes from what I learned $det(AB) = det(A)det(B)$ for two square matrices that can be multiplied together, so even if the order of the multiplication is wrong if you've correctly found the two determinants than your answer is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the properties of the determinant, if we denote by $M$ the modified matrix obtained from $A$, and we apply some elementary column operations conveniently, it results that:
\begin{align*}
\det(M) & = \det[v_{1} + v_{2} + v_{3} \mid v_{2} + 2v_{3} \mid 2v_{2} + 6v_{3}]\\\\
& = \det[v_{1} + v_{2} + v_{3} \mid v_{2} + 2v_{3} \mid 2v_{3}]\\\\
& = 2\det[v_{1} + v_{2} + v_{3} \mid v_{2} + 2v_{3} \mid v_{3}]\\\\
& = 2\det[v_{1} + v_{2} + v_{3} \mid v_{2} \mid v_{3}]\\\\
& = 2\det[v_{1} \mid v_{2} \mid v_{3}] = 2\times 2 = 4.
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!